# What´s the better way to create minor entitites resources in nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I´m starting with `nestjs` and I want to create an application with a kind of 20 tables in the database, what's the better way to create these resources in my code? should I create a new resource for each table in the database? I can't find information about this.

Is there an easy way to create migrations among the models created in the resources?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you Typeorm
With typeorm you can connect with any database and migration is so easy
And also typeorm use code first you your tables and fields all in the backend code which is nestjs then you can sync or migrate it to get real tables
You can read more about from here
https://typeorm.io/